# How to hide gvim's backup files under Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vim, gvim

How to hide gvim's backup files under Windows XP?

EDIT: I think I have mistaken backup files as swap files. Actually I mean the files that end with `~`. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the answer below when the question was about Vim’s swap files. The same idea applies for Vim’s backup files with the option [`'backupdir'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupdir') instead of `'directory'` (i.e. use a central directory for the backup files to keep them out of the way).

---

You could use a central location for the swap files. It would not “flip the hidden bit”, but it would effectively get them out of the way. See the documentation for [`'directory'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'directory').

Place one of the following in your `.vimrc`/`_vimrc` (e.g. `:e $HOME/.vimrc`):

```
" Remove the current directory from the list of places that swap files might be created.
set directory-=.

" OR

" Explicit list of locations for swap files.
"   The double trailing slash makes the otherwise centralized swap files use
"   filenames that are based on the full pathname of the edited file
"   (this lets you edit (e.g.) README files from two different places without
"   getting colliding swap file names).
set directory=c:\\tmp//,c:\\temp//
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to hide the backup files would be to put them in a separate directory. See

```
:help backupdir
```

Another way might be to use the `BufWritePost` autocommand to set the backup file's hidden attribute after it's written.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the backup file (the one with the ~ at the end) from being created, add the following to the end of the _vimrc file:

set nobackup

set nowritebackup

Answer (score 0):

Hide or completely turn that off?

If the latter is OK, put to your *.vimrc* file line

`set noswapfile`

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggested an autocmd to set the filesystem's "hidden" attribute.

I wrote a plugin to do just that: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4505